# How to make a keypress event to fire only once in JS

Tags: javascript, eventhandler, onkeypress

How can I prevent the function move() to be triggered multiple times when I hold the button down? I'd like it to fire only once even though the user is holding the key down.

```
function pushbtn(event)
{
    var pressBtn = event.keyCode;
    //Move to the right
    if(pressBtn==100)
    {
        move(1933.67);


    }
    //Move to the left
    else if(pressBtn==113)
    {
        move(-1933.67);

    }
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', pushbtn);
document.addEventListener('keyup', releasebtn);
```

Answer (score -1):

dmaurolizer's [KeyPress library](https://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/) gives fine control over all keyboard events.  You provide callback functions for events.  The `keydown` event sends an optional `isRepeat` param so you can ignore auto-repeats.  Here's a sample using that functionality for the thrust control in a video game:

```
var my_combos = listener.register_many([
    {
        "keys"          : "up",
        "on_keydown"    : function(e, num, isRepeat) {
            if (isRepeat) return ;
            thrust = 0.1;
        },
        "on_keyup"      : function() {
            thrust = 0;
        }
    }
]);
```